# Django Updating Existing Model field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, insert-update, updatemodel

I have a model in Django with a foreign key to Django User Model. I am trying to update my model with a form, but database isn't updating. I can't figure out the problem.

## model.py

```
from django.conf import settings

    class UserInfo(models.Model):
        username = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
        owner =  models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
```

## form.py

```
from django import forms
from society.models import UserInfo

    class Editform(forms.ModelForm):
        username=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'onchange': 'this.form.submit();', 'class': 'editinput'}))
        class Meta:
            model = UserInfo
            fields ='__all__'
```

## views.py

```
 from django.shortcuts import render
    from society.models import UserInfo
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from society.forms import Editform

        def ProfileView(request):
            user = request.user
            username = UserInfo.objects.get(owner=user)
            if request.method == 'POST':
                form = Editform(request.POST, instance=username)
                if form.is_valid():
                    form.save()
            else:
                form = Editform(instance=username)


            return render (request, 'profile_view.html', {'user':username, 'form':form})
```

## url.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
import society.views

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', 'society.views.home'),
        url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
        url(r'^login/', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
        url(r'^logout/', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout'),
        url(r'^userreg/', 'society.views.UserReg'),
        url(r'^profile/', 'society.views.ProfileView'),
    ]
```

## profile_view.html

```
    <div>
        <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
            {{form.username}}
            {{user.username}}
        </form>
    </div>
```

When ever I change form.username, user.username change instantly but the database is not updating. I tried with adding a submit button, but still no luck.

Answer (score 4):

You should pass record id for updating existing UserInfo record.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from society.models import UserInfo
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from society.forms import Editform

def ProfileView(request):
    user_id = request.POST.get('user_id')
    user = UserInfo.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Editform(request.POST, instance=user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = Editform(instance=user)

    return render (request, 'profile_view.html', {'user':username, 'form':form})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can update in 2 method for eg: here i am going to update Your username,

1) if you using `object.get()`:

```
get_name = UserInfo.objects.get(owner=user)
get_name['username'] = 'Your Input what you need to change'
get_name.save()
```

2) if you using `object.filter()`:

```
get_name = UserInfo.objects.filter(owner=user).update(username='your data') # or form.username
```

Thats it..

Comment: I think for using filter you need to get object of FK table(whatever table's PK you use as FK in your table) then need to apply update query.

Comment: Foreign Key Update also will work in filter.. I am using this.. even doing modelname__in this also

Answer (score 1):

Apart from anything else, you haven't pointed your form at anything, so the form can't connect to the logic of the view - in effect, you've specified the form should POST content, but not where to.

The form should point to a URL in your urls.py file, which is of course linked to the view you've shown above.  That works in the following way:

```
<form action="{% url 'core.views.new_comment' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %} 
...
</form>
```

There's more guidance [about how this works here in the docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/#building-a-form)   (Obviously people know that the answer's in the docs, the trick is finding it. :) )

(Also, your formatting is off in the views.py, but I think that's just a cut and paste problem when entering the question.)

Comment: '<form action="{% url 'society.views.ProfileView' %}"method="post">
{% csrf_token %}

</form>'

I tried this. not working.... @withnail

Comment: What errors are you getting?  What does the test server say when you're posting?

Comment: no error. But database isn't updating. suppose I changed user name x to y. The user.username instantly changed to y. but when I reload page its been always x.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway I soloved this problem, Thank You everyone. Just Changed the form.py

from django import forms
from society.models import UserInfo

```
class Editform(forms.ModelForm):
    username=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'onchange': 'this.form.submit();', 'class': 'editinput'}))
    class Meta:
        model = UserInfo
        exclude =('owner',)
```

As owner is a mandatory field, but I omitted it from template it was showing mandatory field error. Its working now. Thanks anyway.